# Is there any C++ STL function to process i and i+1 elements?

Tags: c++, stl

Currently my code is something like this

```
std::vector<int> listOfItems;
// Assume the listOfItems is filled here
for(std::size_t i=0; i<listOfItems.size()-1; i++)
{
   doSomething(listOfItems[i], listOfItems[i+1]);
}
```

I was wondering if I could avoid this code and use any STL algorithms for better readibility.
Thank you

Comment: Something like `std::for_each` maybe?

Comment: But I think in for each you can work only one element at a time, isn't it?

Comment: Correct. But your mutable lambda simply saves each value for the next iteration of the loop (and does not do anything except that the first time it's called).

Comment: You *could* use [`std::adjacent_find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) but don't.  There is nothing wrong with your loop except that `i` should be a `std::size_t` instead of an `int`.  You also need to make sure your vector is not empty before the loop starts.

Comment: As given, the code is undefined behavior.  Because the `listOfItems` is empty, and `listOfItems.size()-1` is a very big unsigned number.

Comment: The code has a bug, because `listOfItems.size()-1` will have a very large value when `listOfItems` is empty. So you need to check for that before running the loop. And once you've got that, don't waste time with `listOfItems.at(i)` and `listOfItems.at(i+1)`; you **know** that `i` and `i+1` are valid indices. Just use `listOfItems[i]` and `listOfItems[i+1]`.

Comment: Sorry this was just dummy code and not actual code, I just wanted to process i and i+1 at a time @Eljay

Comment: Prefer `i + 1 < listOfItems.size()` as the stopping conditional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this in my utility library. Feel free to use it:

```
/** Iterates over each adjacent pair of the range.
 *
 * For the sequence [1, 2, 3, 4], it invokes fn(1, 2), fn(2, 3), fn(3, 4).
 * Nothing is invoked if the sequence is only one element long.
 *
 * @returns The final state of fn.
 */
template <typename FwdIt, typename BinFn>
BinFn for_pairs(FwdIt first, FwdIt last, BinFn fn) {
  if (first == last) {
    return fn;
  }

  for (FwdIt it = std::next(first); it != last; ++first, ++it) {
    fn(*first, *it);
  }

  return fn;
}
```

Comment: What happens if the sequence has an odd number of terms? Come on documentation?

Comment: Even if its odd,  I think its still works I  guess,

Comment: Consider  this
[1,2,3]
calls will be like fn(1,2)  fn(2,3)